# Typing, custom collection type

Tags: python, counter, typing

The typing module provides some handy features to enable better readability and more confidence in the correctness of the code typed.

One of the best features is that you can write something like below to describe an input dictionary with specified element-types.

```
def myFun(inputDict:Dict[str, int]): pass
```

Now I wonder, can this be "extended" to custom types? Can custom types (which act like containers) be provided indices in a formal way to tell a potential type checker the contents must be of a specific type?

For example the `collections.Counter` class? - Above constraint won't work when I really want a counter, since dictionaries do not provide addition operator, where counters do.

I could do something like:

```
def myFun(inputDict:collections.Counter): pass
```

But then I lose information on what the counter stores. - Is using a `TypeVar` the right approach here?

```
CounterTy = typing.TypeVar("CounterTy", collections.Counter)
def myFun(inputDict:CounterTy[str]): pass
```

I'm not clear if `Typevar` is supposed to work that way or not. EDIT: just to be clear, above code doesn't work and errors on the `TypeVar` line.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `typing.Generic` if you're trying to implement your own types. Unfortunately, `collections.Counter` isn't type-hinted at all, so you can't use that syntax with it.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks but that confuses me, I tried `typing.Generic[str]` - but that returns "TypeError: Initial parameters must be type variables; got <class 'str'>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're writing your own container type and want to parameterize it the same way `typing.Dict` and other types are, you should use `typing.Generic` as one of your bases (with a `TypeVar` as its parameter):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Iterable

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyContainer(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, iterable:Iterable[T]):
        ...

    def foo(self) -> T:
        ...

def some_function(arg: MyContainer[str]) -> str:
    return arg.foo()
```